# Sort elements of an XDocument based on their grandchild

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML (shown in abbreviated form) loaded into an XDocument object.

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <identification>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    </identification>
    <payment contractType="1">
      <income type="4" startDate="2014-10-01" endDate="2014-10-31">
      </income>
    </payment>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <identification>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Balmer</lastName>
    </identification>
    <payment contractType="2">
      <income type="2" startDate="2014-10-01" endDate="2014-10-31">
      </income>              
    </payment>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

I want to apply a linq query on my XDocument object that sorts all  nodes based on `<lastname>` then by `<firstname>` using Linq to XML. Thus, after applying linq my XDocument object will contain the following XML:

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <identification>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Balmer</lastName>
    </identification>
    <payment contractType="2">
      <income type="2" startDate="2014-10-01" endDate="2014-10-31">
      </income>
    </payment>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <identification>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    </identification>
    <payment contractType="1">
      <income type="4" startDate="2014-10-01" endDate="2014-10-31">
      </income>              
    </payment>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: any attempts so far?

Comment: @decPL i tried sth like orderby e.Element(XMLGenerator.nsDefault + "identification").Element(XMLGenerator.nsDefault + "lastname").Value but i am getting an inner exception

Comment: @decPL where -> e = from e in xDoc.Descendants(XMLGenerator.nsDefault + "employee")

Comment: I would simplify your schema `<employee firstName="" lastName="">`

Comment: @ChaosPandion this is not possible. the schema is provided as is by the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Extract "employee" Xelements in order.
var orderedEmployees = 
    from employee in xml.Descendants("employee")
    orderby employee.Element("identification").Element("lastName").Value,
            employee.Element("identification").Element("firstName").Value
    select employee;

// Build a new Xelement with the original root and orderded "employee" elements.
var result = new XElement(xml.Root.Name,
                 from employee in orderedEmployees
                 select new XElement(employee)
             );
```

Comment: I can't believe it. That's exactly what I've been doing in my code (see comment in question). Once I've pasted your answer in my project it is working ok without an exception any more

Comment: You only have to switch firstName with lastName

Comment: ha ha ha ... i had lastName written as lastname in my code ... argghhh

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, sorry to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, just to give you an idea:

```
var sorted = new XDocument(
                new XElement(
                   "employees",
                   ORIGINAL_XDOC.Descendants("employee")
                                .OrderBy(e => e.Descendants("lastName")
                                               .Single()
                                               .Value)
                                .ThenBy(e => e.Descendants("firstName")
                                              .Single()
                                              .Value)));
```

Comment: I think you got `firstName` and `lastName` backwards.

Comment: @decPL your code gives me an empty <employees/> element once applied on my data

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Which would imply that your XML might differ somehow - I've tested this on the XML you've provided in LINQPAD and it worked. Please verify - if you still have problems I'll post the complete code sample offsite tomorrow.